# Area 51 incorrectly counts total rep from Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, documentation, reputation, area-51

Not sure this one belongs here, but since Documentation belongs to Stack Overflow I'll post it here I guess.

[image: Duplication example]

It gives me 2x the 7,158 from Stack Overflow, one time from Documentation and one time from Stack Overflow.

Comment: The challenge: Get "Time Travel" through 100% commitment before the devs get a chance to fix this (I am kidding, KIDDING, please don't go do that, and if you have, please go back in time and don't do that).